# Is there an opposite for "welcome"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I was going through [an answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/15827/143251) in a post where they define how rough can people be to new users in some cases. There I read:

> I have known many good developers that would not use it because of this particular **welcoming** behavior.

As you see, in this specific case *welcome* is not following its etymological form of *well* + *come*. Instead, is something like *not well come*.

So, is there an opposite for "welcome"? Could "unwelcome" or "unwelcoming" serve for this purpose? I don't know if such words even exist, since searching for them redirects me to the [welcome entry in Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/unwelcome?s=t).

Comment: Yes, "unwelcome" is perfectly acceptable. For example: "The snobby guests at the party made me feel quite *unwelcome*."

Comment: unwelcome is given in the link that you gave with an example that makes it clear that it exists and has the usage you require!

Comment: Even if the opposite of "well" is "ill", it doesn't mean the opposite of "welcome" is "illcome".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Both [unwelcome](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unwelcome) and [unwelcoming](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unwelcoming) are valid antonyms of *welcome* resp. *welcoming*:

**unwelcome**:

> **not wanted**:
>   unwelcome news
>   an unwelcome visitor

**unwelcoming**:

> **not making a guest or visitor feel happy, comfortable, or wanted**:
>   The house was damp and unwelcoming.